# User control blank on form in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

I've created a user control that contains a table layout control with various other standard controls like buttons and labels. Yet when I add the user control to one of my forms the control is blank. I've tried building the solution and a see the user-control flicker as if it's being updated, but it remains blank. Also if I actually run the program the usercontrol can not be see on the form.

I've used usercontrols like this in the past. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have add the default Constructor with `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Perfect, this worked. Apparently when I created a new `UserControl` VS messed up and didn't provide the designer.cs and such - so I manaully 'fixed' it. Though, I forgot to create a default constructor and call that function. Funny how the Winforms designer knows how to draw the control at the site of the `UserControl` rather than when you add an instance of it to another form.

Answer (score 0):

are you combinding autosize on the usercontrol with some sort of Dock, i know i had the same problem when i did so..

Comment: Yes the user control is nested in a group box, and another table layout control, but ultimately inside a split container.

Comment: .. however I tried adding the control the a new empty form an the control is still blank.